# Stack Exchange CDN intermittently very slow lately

Tags: support, cdn

I am behind an office firewall, likely located in Munich

My smartphone via Amsterdam is not affected

I have seen the other answers from 2011 and such, but just this week both JS and CSS have this issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have this from another location too? Are there proxies between you and the internet?

Comment: Yes there is a proxy and no, not that I have noticed

Comment: What is your approximate location? It might be one of the CDN servers is affected.

Comment: Good question, Likely Amsterdam or Munich

Comment: I should be on Amsterdam too and have no issues at all.

Comment: Can you try on a mobile phone with Wifi disabled?

Comment: No problem via t-mobile (Amsterdam?)

Comment: So it is strictly your machine or your network?

Comment: Actually it is intermittent and right now no problem